# Expand div to the left and and to top and bottom evenly

Tags: css, reactjs, position

I want to expand the black rectangle to the left when there is a text in it and also expand it evenly to the bottom and top (so the rectangle and the arrow will stay in its initial place).

Tried lots of things (position, display, float), non of them worked. I also attached images of my current render.

CSS:

```
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -5px;
}

.left .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #000;
  right: -5px;
  left: auto;
}

.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-right-color: #000;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Tooltip3.scss';

const Tooltip3 = ({direction}) => {

    return (
        <div id='tooltip' className={direction}>

            <div className='tooltip-arrow' />
            <div className='tooltip-inner'></div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Tooltip3;
```

Initial Position:
[image: Initial position:]

When writing text:
[image]

Comment: can you make a [mcve] with what you currently have (with rendered html rather than the react)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the way you positioned your `dev.left` element. Use `right` instead of `left` (for example use `right: 100%`)